# Celery - is there way to continue executing chain after subtasks in the middle failed

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I need to find the way how continue executing the chain with *immutable=True* subtasks after any middle subtask throws exception.

I already read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508112/retrying-celery-failed-tasks-that-are-part-of-a-chain) and this [issue comment](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1014#issuecomment-10053136). Now these bugs are fixed, but I need to implement opposite behaviour. I don't need to stop my chain executing. May be there is another **way to execute list of independent tasks one after another in any sequence without sending results between them**? And I need to execute them asynchronously, because in this case django-celery will store statistic about every task.

One solution is to cover body of all subtasks with:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception, e:
    logger.error('Exception raised: %s' % e)
    raise e
```

But in this case all subtasks would be executed with **SUCCESS** status and traceback of exception in *django-celery* admin interface would be useless.

Comment: I have same issue, any resolution?

Comment: @reptilicus no, I didn't find it. As result I completely refactored my celery canvas structure and start using PeriodicTask, which starts another tasks every minute in balanced way

Comment: well that's a bummer!

Answer (score 0):

Perharps using a Chord and the [CELERY_CHORD_PROPAGATES](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#error-handling)

So when a subpart of the Chord failed, you can manage the Exception and do what you want with it (log something, requeue a task for alter execution, etc).

As you already have a chain, the Chord will only be a part of it, with the tasks you need to know the status.

Comment: I don't think it is solution, becouse I don't need to run all subtasks in parallel like it happens inside chord: "Now you can use a chord to calculate each addition step in parallel, and then get the sum of the resulting numbers:" from here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords

Comment: I better figure out your need. I have not the time to test it myself today, but in the doc here : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups it states that group **call** are launch one after the other regarding the result.

Comment: These is said tt's only in case, when you **call** group **sync**. When you call group **async**, they well execute in parallel. The first phrase in paragraph is '*A group can be used to execute several tasks in parallel.*'