# How does Celery handle task failures within a chain?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

What happens when a Celery task within a chain fails?

When the failed task is retried with success, does it simply resume from where it was within a chain?

For example:

```
my_chain = (task1.s() | task2.s() | task3.s())
my_chain.apply_async((**params))
```

If `task2` fails and retried with success, would `task3` then be executed?

There is an old question that touches on the subject ([Retrying celery failed tasks that are part of a chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508112/retrying-celery-failed-tasks-that-are-part-of-a-chain)), and a Github [issue](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/157) and [commit](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/b2b9d922fdaed5571cf685249bdc46f28acacde3) applied to version 3.0.4 of Celery that makes `Task.retry` forward the chain links to remedy this issue. However, I am unable to find any concrete documentation that explains behavior of Celery during this situation.

Definitely, no mention of it within the Celery documentation Retrying sections (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying, http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.retry)

Comment: If task2 succeeds after a task2.retry() call task3 will get executed.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following snippet is the closest thing to describing this.

"When you call retry it will send a new message, using the same task-id, and it will take care to make sure the message is delivered to the same queue as the originating task.

When a task is retried this is also recorded as a task state, so that you can track the progress of the task using the result instance (see States)."

I believe where it state that the task state is tracked best describes what you are looking for.

I also know this based on first hand experience